# How do you debug phpUnit tests with hhvm?

Tags: php, phpunit, hhvm

I couldn't figure out how to get hhvm's debugger to work with phpUnit tests.

Answer (score 1):

Simply run your phpUnit tests in hhvm's debug mode:

```
hhvm -m debug phpunit tests/MyTest.hh
```